# jquery - how to slice elements in two different unordered lists?

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of unordered lists with the same class name and I want to subset it with jquery slice.

```
var currentCount= 0;
var maxCount= 3;
$('.ulClassName>li').slice(currentCount,maxCount).show();
```

This works perfectly for the first UL (it shows only the first three lists) but does not slice the second UL with the same class name. Below is the markup:

```
<ul class="ulClassName" id="firstUL">
 <li>Blah blah1 </li>
 <li>Blah blah2 </li>
 <li>Blah blah3 </li>
 <li>Blah blah4 </li>
 <li>Blah blah5 </li>
 <li>Blah blah6 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="ulClassName" id="secondUL">
 <li>Blah blah1 </li>
 <li>Blah blah2 </li>
 <li>Blah blah3 </li>
 <li>Blah blah4 </li>
```

I understand that jquery indexes all list elements in the page, I dont want to write separate code for the two lists, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to call:

```
$('.ulClassName').each(function() {
   $(this).find('li').slice(currentCount, maxCount).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the `nth-child` selector combined with `nextAll` to avoid using `slice`, which operates on the entire set all at once:

```
$('.ulClassName > li:nth-child(4)').prevAll().show();
```

Alternatively,

```
$('.ulClassName > li:nth-child(3) ~ li').hide();
```

(This **hides** everything under the third `li` element, which is different from the first, but should be more efficient since `~ li` can be evaluated by `document.querySelectorAll()` for modern browsers)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.sideFilter').each(function(){ 

$(this).find('li').slice(5).wrap("<ul></ul>");


});
```

Comment: You should really add some non-code comments describing your answer.

Comment: Additionally, since your answer is quite similar to one that has already been accepted, you should describe why your solution may be perfered.